# Autofill And Login to GoogleMail with javascript

Tags: javascript, web, getelementbyid

So I am building a WebApp. There I want to have a Button to open and AutoLogin to the GoogleCalendar. I already tried to create a js but i guess i did something wrong.

The js Code:

```
var popupWindow;
function OpenCalendar() {

popupWindow = window.open('https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=cl', 'Calendar');

popupWindow.focus();

popupWindow.document.getElementById('Email').value = 'mail';
popupWindow.document.getElementById('Passwd').value = 'pass';


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access any resource from other domain through JavaScript. It is restricted due to security reasons. In short this is not possible.

You can take a look at Google Accounts authentication and authorization here at this link https://developers.google.com/accounts/